# Exception in Thread JavaFX application thread Cannot be cast

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx

Last week I posted a question about switching stages/scenes and somebody suggest that I read up on MVC Framework.  I have done that and started converting my application and I get an error now when I try to change the scene.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.WesternAdvance.Lasercontroller.LaserControllerUI cannot be cast to com.WesternAdvance.Lasercontroller.LoginPageController
    at com.WesternAdvance.Lasercontroller.LoginManager.showMainViewAdmin(LoginManager.java:60)
```

The line it is referring to is

```
 loader.<LoginPageController>getController();
```

Here is what I am doing...

I have a login page `loginPage.java` that creates a scene like this:

```
public class LoginPage extends Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
  @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane());

    LoginManager loginManager = new LoginManager(scene);
    loginManager.showLoginScreen();

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    stage.setTitle("Laser Controller");
    stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> System.exit(1));
    stage.setX(0);
    stage.setY(0);
    stage.sizeToScene();
  }
}
```

Then I have a `LoginPageController.java` that checks the password input and compares it to a hash like this:

```
 public void initManager(final LoginManager loginManager) {
  login.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
  @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
      String passwordhashadmin = "$2a$08$WV7EDELlZbLHqrcW5qpuSuc6Bk8PkpvttIqeBi1n0EwP.yLt.tg2K";
      String passwordhashuser = "$2a$08$2eS3Mukla5T.rCC747/hj.FGrP2GHSWCgloP4ZBVuTROYIQWwo6lm";

      if (BCrypt.checkpw(userId.getText() + passwordfield.getText(), passwordhashuser))

    {

          loginManager.showMainViewUser();//Login as User
    }
      else if (BCrypt.checkpw(userId.getText() + passwordfield.getText(), passwordhashadmin))
    {

            loginManager.showMainViewAdmin();
    } 


      else{
        errorMessage.setText("Login Incorrect!");
        System.out.print("false");
          }
  }
}
```

And then depending on which user logs in `LoginManager.java` SHOULD open the correct scene like this...

```
void showMainViewUser() {
    try {
      FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
        getClass().getResource("LaserControllerUserUi.fxml")
      );
      scene.setRoot((Parent) loader.load());
      LoginPageController controller = 
                loader.<LoginPageController>getController();
      controller.initManager(this);
      scene.getStylesheets().add(LaserControllerUI.class.getResource("LaserControllerUI.css").toExternalForm());

    } catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(LoginManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}



void showMainViewAdmin() {     

    try {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
            getClass().getResource("LaserControllerAdminUi.fxml")
          );
          scene.setRoot((Parent) loader.load());
          LoginPageController controller = 
                    loader.<LoginPageController>getController();
                  controller.initManager(this);
          scene.getStylesheets().add(LaserControllerUI.class.getResource("LaserControllerUI.css").toExternalForm());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(LoginManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
  }
```

Why am I getting the error that I am? I am kicking myself for not backing up before I went at it. but all part of the learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

```
LoginPageController controller = loader.<LoginPageController>getController();
```

Will be converted to a equivalent of something like this in byte code because of type erasure:

```
Object temp = loader.getController();
LoginPageController controller = (LoginPageController) temp;
```

If the controller type that is created by the `FXMLLoader` is not assignable to `LoginPageController` a `ClassCastException` happens.

Since the value of the `fx:controller` attribute in `LaserControllerAdminUi.fxml` is `com.WesternAdvance.Lasercontroller.LaserControllerUI` and not `com.WesternAdvance.Lasercontroller.LoginPageController` this happens.